# consume opensearch indices with sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-opensearch

I need to extract data from indices in AWS OpenSearch to make aggregations and analyze anomalies/variations.

***PS**: I think the logic works...*

I'm thinking of using **Sagemaker** + **OpenSearch**. The logic would be as follows: Sagemaker connects to Opensearch, fetches real-time data from the indices, processes it and makes it available via the Sagemaker endpoint, but the following question arose:

What is the difference between communicating with AWS Opensearch using "[OpenSearch Service AI connectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ml-amazon-connector.html#connector-sagemaker-create)" and using the code below?

Connection example:

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection, AWSV4SignerAuth
import boto3

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
host = OPENSEARCH_HOSTNAME["*.es.amazon.com"]

auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, 'us-east-1', 'es')
# Using the opensearch Python client to connect to opensearch cluster.

os_client = OpenSearch(hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
 http_auth = auth,
 use_ssl=True,
 verify_certs=True,
 connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
 timeout=30
 )

print(os_client)

print(os_client.ping())
```